# Trivial program throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when running the above code and  don't know the exact issue. What is the solution for this?

```
using System;

class second
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, {}!", args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the C# station tutorial!");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The error is *"Index out of range"*.

Comment: Your code isn't the same as the [tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorials/lesson01.aspx) you copied it from. Have you actually read that tutorial? I'm sure you will find the answer there.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the argument position

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello,{0}!", args[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `string[] args` parameter is the command-line parameters to the exe. I'm guessing that you didn't pass any arguments, therefore `args[0]` is *out of range*, just like it said. If you ran your exe as:

```
your.exe MyName
```

then it would have at least got past the `IndexOutOfRangeException` - to raise a `FormatException` instead ;p To fix that, change the `{}` to `{0}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. Check to make sure that there are parameters. If not, provide feedback on the console.

```
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No input parameters were received.");
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Where is this to be applied/used? Can you add some indication (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Comment: This would go just above the "Console.WriteLine("Hello, {}!", args[0]);" line

Answer (score 1):

I believe you ran the program off Visual Studio and thus had run the program without passing in any parameter against `arg[]`.

To pass in a parameter `E.g. Scott to arg[]`,

1. go to the Solution Explorer (menu *View* → *Solution Explorer*)
2. select *Properties*.
3. Input "Scott" into the *"Command Line arguments"* textbox under the *Start Options* section.

   The program will run as normal. See the image below.

[image: b]

Answer (score 0):

If args has zero items, then attempting to get the first index of it (i.e. 0) will cause an index out of bounds exception. You should check that args isn't null or empty before attempting to reference an index within it. If you ran that example with some command line arguments it would probably work.